# How to insert a 'string+ file name' in the file text in commnad line bash shell?

Tags: bash

I am working on a problem, As part of that I have got some 30,000 files with some content in it. What I want is that I want `name:filename` inside the file text, but since I have got so many files, it is not practical for me to go through each file and do it manually. Is there any way I can do it using shell?

```
$ cat file1
text1,text2
```

What I want is this:

```
$ cat file1
text1,text2
name:file1
```

I have written this code,

```
for i in `ls`; do echo $i >> $i; done;
```

What this is doing is that it is adding the file name as a string at the end, Is there any way I can add `name:filename`, instead of just `filename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you need

```
for i in *; do echo "name:$i" >> $i; done
```

Comment: yes that worked.

Comment: @JoeDimaggio Note that it's `for i in *; do …`. [Don't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).